# simple web proxy server for windows

Tags: windows, proxy-server

I am looking for a simple web proxy server that anybody can use. I mean it should be executable and not commandline/service. Something like squid/polipo but with a windows interface. It should also be able to cache and should be free of charge.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You use FreeProxy. It is free of charge, a windows executable, with a easy-to-user GUI interface. Also it has features like authentication, caching and url-filtering.

You can download FreeProxy from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Proxy-Servers/FreeProxy.shtml).

Another alternate is CCProxy. Still I would prefer FreeProxy over this. You can download CCProxy from [here](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/ccproxysetup7.2.exe).

Comment: Great option. Hadn't found it until you mentioned it. Hidden gem :)

Comment: The FreeProxy website seems dead as of October 2015 (some download links are broken) and the software does not install properly under Windows 10. It was a great software while it lasted but it looks like it's time to look for an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest AnalogX proxy. It is really simple, and I have used it numerous times to solve my proxying problem.

Get it at http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/proxy/Freeware.htm

See my blog on how to configure the proxy at: http://sharuzzaman.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssh-reverse-tunnel-one-way-connection.html

Answer (score 3):

It is more complex than what you need, but [AdvOR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advtor/files/AdvOR-0.2.0.8/) would do it.

> Advanced Onion Router is a client for OR network and is intended to be an improved alternative for Tor+Vidalia+Privoxy bundle for Windows users. It is able to "force" a program and its plugins to use the Tor proxy regardless of its configured proxy

Comment: Does not look very simple. Something like winroute would be perfect if it was free

Comment: Vidalia has a GUI for poplipo if you are interested...

Comment: Vidalia has something to do with tor??? I don't want lots of small tools i have to learn about. I want an application with some settings ;)

Comment: I do like AdvOr for it's simplicity but it does not have caching.

Comment: It caches, but not web data (just certs). It sounds like you want to configure a web server to act as a proxy?

Answer (score 2):

I've installed and worked with ccproxy, 
it's free up to 3 users and very simple to install and use, 
I really recommend it!

for **superusers** there's also another nice and totally free proxy, **Polipo**.
It's bundled with tor,

you can download tor from [Tor Project Website](http://www.torproject.org),
Tor has three modules:

- tor
- vidalia : is used to configure tor
- polipo : is used as a proxy server, by default only local clients can connect to tor, but if you'd like you can use polipo.conf to set **allowedClients** for remote ones.

Good Luck!